# How to solve the following equation? I already know the solution but not the way.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

\begin{equation} 100.000=40.000*\frac{(1+r)^4-1}{r*(1+r)^4} \end{equation}

I already came this far:

\begin{equation} 2,5r(1+r)^4 =(1+r)^4-1 \end{equation}

and I know that one soluiton ist r=21,86, but I can't find the way.

Comment: Did you mean $r = 0.218623$? There is also a negative $r$.

Comment: Yes this is one of the r. I think there is one negative and two more complex solutions, but I can't simplify the equation.

Comment: **Hint:** What if you let $y = (r+1)$? Substitute that in the two places and then  sub $r = y-1$ for the other and now see if that makes simplifying things a low easier. Another approach is to expand both sides of what you wrote and then simplify and solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use @Moo's hint, using whole numbers, you need to solve for $r$ a quartic equation since after factoring, you have
$$r \left(5 r^4+18 r^3+22 r^2+8 r-3\right)=0$$ which is doable with (awful) radicals.

If you use @Moo's hint, that is to say $r=y-1$, you need to find the zero of function
$$f(y)=5 y^5-7 y^4+2$$
Its first derivative cancels at $y_*=\frac{28}{25}$. Make $y=\frac{28}{25}+z$ and look at
$$g(z)=-\frac{396342}{1953125}+\frac{10976 }{625}z^2+\frac{784 }{25}z^3+21 z^4+5
   z^5$$

Using only the first and second term, then
$$z=\frac{3 }{700}\sqrt{\frac{22019}{35}}\implies y=\frac{28}{25}+\frac{3 }{700}\sqrt{\frac{22019}{35}}\implies r=\frac{3}{25}+\frac{3 }{700}\sqrt{\frac{22019}{35}}=0.227495$$ which is a first approximation.

But, nuermically, the above $z$ is almost $\frac 1 {10}$ , then make $z=t+\frac 1 {10}$
$$h(t)=\frac{387431}{62500000}+\frac{226981 }{50000}t+\frac{70699 }{2500}t^2+\frac{2013}{50}t^3+\frac{47 }{2}t^4+5 t^5$$ Using again the first and second terms
$$t=-\frac{387431}{283726250}\implies r=\frac{3}{25}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{387431}{283726250}=\frac{31016172}{141863125}=0.218634$$ and we could continue for ever just solving a linear equation.

For your curiosity, this is the process Newton followed  to invent Newton method.